# Running arquillian test with liberty:dev goal

Tags: websphere, jboss-arquillian, open-liberty

I need to run Arquillian IT with hot reload implemented by the liberty:dev goal. 
How to configure Arquillian with open liberty when using the configure "mvn clean liberty:dev" goal?
It looks like the `configure-arquillian` goal:

```
<execution>
    <id>configure-arquillian-xml</id>
    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>configure-arquillian</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

is never executed when I use the command `mvn clean liberty:dev` and when I run the tests while hitting "enter".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by the liberty:dev goal at the moment. There is a GitHub issue to add support for this here: https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven/issues/848

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I've been trying doing this for a few days now... thanks again